# Azure Pipelines is not using the NuGet version specified

Tags: azure, azure-devops, nuget, yaml, azure-web-app-service

This is my original YML file.

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:

- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
  displayName: "NuGet use 4.9.3"
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 4.9.3

- task: DotNetCoreInstaller@0
  inputs:
    version: '2.2.104'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: "NuGet Restore"
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '**/*.csproj'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: ".NET build"
  inputs:
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: --configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --no-restore

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: ".NET publish package"
  inputs:
    command: publish
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --no-restore --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app/pkg'
```

This is the output I get for the Nuget Restore step.

> [section]Starting: NuGet restore
>   ============================================================================== Task         : NuGet Description  : Restore, pack, or push NuGet
>   packages, or run a NuGet command. Supports NuGet.org and authenticated
>   feeds like Package Management and MyGet. Uses NuGet.exe and works with
>   .NET Framework apps. For .NET Core and .NET Standard apps, use the
>   .NET Core task. Version      : 2.147.6 Author       : Microsoft
>   Corporation Help         : [More
>   Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613747)
>   ============================================================================== Caching tool: NuGet 4.1.0 x64 Found tool in cache: NuGet 4.1.0 x64
>   Resolved from tool cache: 4.1.0 Using version: 4.1.0 Found tool in
>   cache: NuGet 4.1.0 x64

How do I disable the use of "tool cache"? It is using 4.1.0 instead of 4.9.3.

UPDATE: As recommended by the comments, I updated my YML file.

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'vs2017-win2016'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: restore

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: ".NET build"
  inputs:
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: --configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --no-restore

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: ".NET publish package"
  inputs:
    command: publish
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --no-restore --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app/pkg'
```

I still get errors.

It's still doing the same thing.

> Starting NuGet restore
>
> Task         : NuGet 
>   Description  : Restore, pack, or push NuGet
>   packages, or run a NuGet command. Supports NuGet.org and authenticated
>   feeds like Package Management and MyGet. Uses NuGet.exe and works with
>   .NET Framework apps. For .NET Core and .NET Standard apps, use the
>   .NET Core task. Version      : 2.147.6 Author       : Microsoft
>   Corporation Help         : More
>   Information h t t p s ://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613747
>
> Caching tool: NuGet 4.1.0 x64 Found tool in cache: NuGet 4.1.0 x64
>   Resolved from tool cache: 4.1.0 Using version: 4.1.0 Found tool in
>   cache: NuGet 4.1.0 x64 SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
>   SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true [command]C:\windows\system32\chcp.com
>   65001 Active code page: 65001 Detected NuGet version 4.1.0.2450 /
>   4.1.0 SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true Saving NuGet.config to a temporary config file.
>   [command]C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\NuGet\4.1.0\x64\nuget.exe sources
>   Add -NonInteractive -Name NuGetOrg -Source
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/ -ConfigFile
>   d:\a\1\Nuget\tempNuGet_57.config Package Source with Name: NuGetOrg
>   added successfully. Saving NuGet.config to a temporary config file.

Why is it even doing a Nuget Restore when it is no longer in my YML file?

Comment: Try to add this `noCache: true` to the NuGet restore task.

Comment: I'd be surprised if it works on Ubuntu, given the task description: Uses **NuGet.exe**. If this is a .NET Core application, use `dotnet restore`.

Comment: No luck it's still doing the same thing.

Comment: I ended up using the YML file in the Microsoft Docs sample and using windows-2019. It worked. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/pipelines-dotnet-core/blob/master/azure-pipelines.yml

Answer (score 4):

This is working for me

```
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use NuGet 4.9.x'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 4.9.x

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(Pipeline.TriggerDirectory)/Library.sln'
    vstsFeed: '[your feed here]'
    noCache: true
```

### Log

#### Tool install

> [section]Starting: Use NuGet 4.9.x
> =========================================================================
> Task         : NuGet Tool Installer
> Description  : Acquires a specific version of NuGet from the internet or the
> tools cache and adds it to the PATH. Use this task to change the version of NuGet used in the NuGet tasks.
> Version      : 0.145.0
> Author       : Microsoft Corporation
> Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=852538)
> =========================================================================
> You are using a query match on the version string. Behavior changes or breaking changes might occur as NuGet updates to a new version.
> Downloading: https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/v4.9.3/nuget.exe
> Caching tool: NuGet 4.9.3 x64
> Using version: 4.9.3
> Found tool in cache: NuGet 4.9.3 x64
> Using tool path: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\NuGet\4.9.3\x64
> Prepending PATH environment variable with directory: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\NuGet\4.9.3\x64
> [section]Finishing: Use NuGet 4.9.x

#### Package restore

> [section]Starting: NuGet restore
> =========================================================================
> Task         : NuGet
> Description  : Restore, pack, or push NuGet packages, or run a NuGet command. Supports NuGet.org and authenticated feeds like Package Management and MyGet. Uses NuGet.exe and works with .NET Framework apps. For .NET Core and .NET Standard apps, use the .NET Core task.
> Version      : 2.147.6
> Author       : Microsoft Corporation
> Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613747)
> =========================================================================
> SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
> SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
> [command]C:\windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
> Active code page: 65001
> Detected NuGet version 4.9.3.5777 / 4.9.3+e5150f1e119e456e01c4f1e413213d392eda1c3a
> SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
> Saving NuGet.config to a temporary config file.
> [command]C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\NuGet\4.9.3\x64\nuget.exe

Comment: This was a great answer and it lead me to the MS documentation of the NuGetToolInstaller@0 task:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/nuget?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 1):

The tools installer and NuGet tasks are more appropriate for Windows machines. Since you're using an Ubuntu agent, just use the `dotnet restore` command:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: restore
```

Comment: No luck. It is still using the same NuGet even with the change.

Comment: Does it look at my YML? Why is it still doing a NuGet Restore when I don't have a step for it anymore?

Comment: I ended up using the YML file in the Microsoft Docs sample and using windows-2019. It worked. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/pipelines-dotnet-core/blob/master/azure-pipelines.yml